# how can I keep the space allocated in DOM when using CSS display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am aware of display:none and visibility:hidden functionality. Due to some reason I have to use display:none and still want to keep the space allocated for the element in DOM so that it doesn't affect other elements next to it. Is it possible?

This is a follow up question as I have pointed out the issue is because of display:none property. Link to the original question is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650205/jquery-how-can-i-add-a-fade-in-out-effect-to-my-function-instead-of-just-setti)

UPDATE: As requested by T.J. Crowder, I am including all the relevant details from my original question over here.

Can you tell me how can I add a nice fade effect for smoother animation to my function instead of setting visibility hidden / visible at an regular interval.

I am not looking for a plugin or add jQuery UI library.

**My JS** :

```
setBlinkingInterval: function(elem, event) {
    if (intervalIdForBlinking != 0) 
        window.clearInterval(intervalIdForBlinking);

    $(elem).show();
    intervalIdForBlinking = setInterval(function() {
       if (eventsObj.eventIsFinished(event)) {
          timer.setClosedStatus(elem, event);
       }
       else {
          if (elem.css('visibility') == 'hidden') 
             elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
         else 
             elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
       }
   }, 500);
}
```

Update 1: HTML markup in order to clarify one answer

```
$('<span/>')
            .append('<div id="closing_blink" class="yellowText" style="display:none;">' + closing + '&nbsp;</div>')
            .append(date.formatFullDate(new Date(event.timeUtc)) + timezone)
            .append('<br/>')
            .append((weatherInfo != '' && trackInfo != '') ? '<div class="whiteText">' + weather + '</div>' + '<div class="orangeText">' + weatherInfo + '</div>' + '&nbsp;' + '<div class="whiteText">' + track + '</div>' + '<div class="orangeText">' + trackInfo + '</div>' : '')
            .appendTo(rightTd);
```

**So after implementing the solutions based on the provided answers I am having issues when it is displayed on the page.**

Case 1: When using my original solution (It works fine)

Screen recorder link [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23650205/jquery-how-can-i-add-a-fade-in-out-effect-to-my-function-instead-of-just-setti)

Case 2: When using fade in/out method (Display issue)

Screen recorder link [HERE](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c2h2QMn45S)

Case 3: When using toggle method (Display issue)

Screen recorder link [HERE](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c2h2QEn45M)

Is there any quick fix to solve the display issue?

Here is the complete HTML up generated by a JS function
drawRaceHead: function(event) {

```
// Returning all race numbers to default values
styling.makeAllRaceNumbersUnselected();

// Make the race number active (including Racing Specials)
styling.makeCurrentEventNumberSelected(event)

// Race info
$("#raceInfo").html('');
$("#raceInfo").append($('<table/>').append($('<tr/>')))
var leftTd = $('<td style="width: 295px"/>')
        .appendTo($('#raceInfo')),
    rightTd = $('<td/>')
        .appendTo($('#raceInfo'));
// If not Racing Specials category
if (event.parentCategoryId != 2863) leftTd.html(raceFullName + '&nbsp;' + event.name)
else leftTd.html(event.name);

$('<div id="closing_time" style="display:none"/>')
    .appendTo(leftTd)

// Date, time, weather, track
var weatherInfo = '', trackInfo = '';
if (event.markets.length > 0) {
    weatherInfo = (event.markets[0].weather == null) ? '-' : event.markets[0].weather;
    trackInfo = (event.markets[0].track == null) ? '-' : event.markets[0].track;
}

var isMSIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
var ieVersion = (function(reg) { return isMSIE && navigator.userAgent.match(reg) ? RegExp.$1 * 1 : null; })(/MSIE\s([0-9]+[\.0-9]*)/);

if (isMSIE && ieVersion < 11) {
    timezone = '';
}
else {
    var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/, timezone = (regExp.exec(new Date)[1]).split(' ')[0];
    timezone = ' (' + timezone + ')';
}

$('<span/>')
    .append('<div id="closing_blink" class="yellowText" style="display:none;">' + closing + '&nbsp;</div>')
    .append(date.formatFullDate(new Date(event.timeUtc)) + timezone)
    .append('<br/>')
    .append((weatherInfo != '' && trackInfo != '') ? '<div class="whiteText">' + weather + '</div>' + '<div class="orangeText">' + weatherInfo + '</div>' + '&nbsp;' + '<div class="whiteText">' + track + '</div>' + '<div class="orangeText">' + trackInfo + '</div>' : '')
    .appendTo(rightTd);
```

},

Comment: don't use `display: none`, use `visibility: hidden`

Comment: wrap the element which is gonna be hidden around another div.

Comment: create a dummy element with same width/height/position and hide the original one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** This answer has sections, based on updates from the OP.

---

Instead of `display: none`, use [`visibility: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility). That hides the element, but the element still takes up space in the layout.

You can see the difference by comparing [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/joracaxo/1) using `display: none` with [this one](http://jsbin.com/joracaxo/2) using `visibility: hidden`.

Both of those use this HTML:

```
<div>This is above</div>
<div id="toggleme">This is the one that toggles</div>
<div>This is below</div>
```

The first uses:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var toggleme = document.getElementById("toggleme");
  setInterval(function() {
    if (toggleme.style.visibility === "hidden") {
      toggleme.style.visibility = "";
    }
    else {
      toggleme.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }, 400);
});
```

while the second uses:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var toggleme = document.getElementById("toggleme");
  setInterval(function() {
    if (toggleme.style.display === "none") {
      toggleme.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
      toggleme.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, 400);
});
```

---

You've said in a comment below you're using `fadeOut` to hide the element. That will, of course, set `display: none` when done. As Arun points out, you can use `fadeTo` instead, which animates `opacity` down to `0`, which has a similar effect to setting `visibility: hidden`: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/bebiyide/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>fadeTo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>This is above</div>
<div id="hideme">This is the one that toggles</div>
<div>This is below</div>
  <script>
    $("#hideme").fadeTo("slow", 0);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Another option is to use the "complete" callback on `fadeOut` to change `display` and `visibility`: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/bebiyide/2)

```
$("#hideme").fadeOut(function() {
  $(this).css({
    display: "",
    visibility: "hidden"
  });
});
```

---

You've asked how you can apply the above to your code. The code looks overly-complex to me (not sure what the whole `eventObj` thing is about), but here's something I think you can readily adapt: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/bebiyide/3)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>faded blinking</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>This is above</div>
<div id="toggleme">This is the one that toggles</div>
<div>This is below</div>
<input type="button" id="btnStartStop" value="Start">
  <script>
    (function() {
      var obj = {
        startBlinking: function($elem) {
          if ($elem.data("blinking")) {
            return;
          }
          $elem.data("blinking", true);
          fadeToZero();

          function fadeToZero() {
            if ($elem.data("blinking")) {
              $elem.fadeTo("slow", 0, fadeToFull);
            }
          }
          function fadeToFull() {
            if ($elem.data("blinking")) {
              $elem.fadeTo("slow", 1, fadeToZero);
            }
          }
        },
        stopBlinking: function($elem) {
          $elem.data("blinking", false);
        }
      };

      $("#btnStartStop").click(function() {
        if (this.value === "Start") {
          obj.startBlinking($("#toggleme"));
          this.value = "Stop";
        }
        else {
          obj.stopBlinking($("#toggleme"));
          this.value = "Start";
        }
      })
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder In my jQuery function I am using fade in/out method which transform the element into Display property instead of visibility. Can you please have a look at my original question(Link is there in my question desc).

Comment: @Nish In that case you try to use `fadeTo()`

Comment: @Nish: Always put all of the relevant code and markup **in** the question, not hidden away in a linked page.

Comment: @Nish: As Arun says, you can use `fadeTo` for that, I've added an example.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I might go with the fadeTo method. However, I have updated the linked page question desc with complete HTML markup, which I am generating through one of my JS function. Do you see where is the problem? You can also have a look at the recorded clip showing the outcome.

Comment: @Nish: Again: Put all of the relevant code and markup in the question, not hidden away in a linked page. This is an SO requirement. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Done. I thought you wanted me to complete the linked question description with complete HTML markup.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder If I use this if (!$(elem).is(':visible')) {
     $(elem).fadeTo(3000, 1);
    } else {
     $(elem).fadeTo(3000, 0);
    }. Why doesn't it trigger the opacity back to 1? It only set the opacity to 0 in the beginning.

Comment: @Nish: With the jQuery docs offline, truthfully I don't know. :-) Apparently `:visible` isn't `false` when `opacity` is `0`, because it doesn't work with `.is(":visible")` ([link](http://jsbin.com/yawawepi/1)) but it works with `.css("opacity") != 0` ([link](http://jsbin.com/yawawepi/2)). Note also that to use a specific duration value, even though it's a number, you have to put it in a string for jQuery to realize that's not the target opacity. Separately: I've added an example of blinking that doesn't require the check at all.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks .css("opacity") != 0 did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use css:

```
.hidemeplease {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```